# what is this mean in the ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm new in Java, and I have seen a ArrayList example like this.

```
  listing = new ArrayList<Lot>();
```

I know that if I want to create an empty array list. Then I will use `ArrayList()`

But I don't understand what is the `<Lot>` between the "`ArrayList`" and "`()`".

Can someone explain it to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Java Generics. The `<Lot>` indicates that the ArrayList will contain only objects of type Lot. It is useful because the compiler can do type checking on your ArrayList.

Answer (score 4):

It is called as type parameter. It denotes that `ArrayList` will only contain objects of type `Lot`
Check out concept of [Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html).

You will get the use of this `ArrayList<Lot>` with this example :

```
// (a)Without Generics ....   
List myIntList = new ArrayList();                  // 1
myIntList.add(new Lot(0));                         // 2
Lot x = (Lot) myIntList.iterator().next();         // 3 


// (b)With Generics ....
List<Lot> myIntList = new ArrayList<Lot>();        // 1’
myIntList.add(new Lot(0));                         // 2’
Lot x = myIntList.iterator().next();               // 3
```

Two points to be noted in the above e.g

1. In `e.g(b)`, Since we already specified that `ArrayList` will contain only objects of type Lot, `in Line 3`, we didn't have to perform casting it to type object Lot. This is because the compiler already know that it will have only Lot type of objects.
2. Trying to add any other type of object to `e.g (b)` will result in compile time error. This is because the compiler has already identified this List is specific to contain elements of only type `Lot`. This is called `type checking`

Answer (score 0):

[It is an extension to Java's type system called, Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Generics allow you to create a `List` that contains a specific sub-type of `Object`s (or a specific set of `Object`s that implement particular interfaces, instead of a collection that only holds plain `Object`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
listing = new ArrayList<Lot>();
```

this line just says that the type of objects to be inserted,updated,retrieved in or from *ArrayList* are of the type *Lot*.
    This is what is called the generics in java.
    Using the generics type casting is not required at the time of retrieval of objects from any List.